# Prevent route from loading until data is available in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In the app I'm working on there is a situation in which data is pulled from a JSON file and is referenced in all subsequent routes. I want to ensure that a route does not load until this data is available, and if not available request it before loading the route. I'm trying to use a route resolve to accomplish this but am finding that the route will load regardless since the request to get the data returns a promise in the resolve. Here's an example of how the code for this is set up, is there a way to not load the route until the promise is resolved? I think the use of promises are throwing me off some.

Factory which pulls the data from the JSON file.

```
    .factory('jsonFactory', function($q, $http) {
        return {
            getFormStuff: function() {
                var deferred = $q.defer(),
                    httpPromise = $http.get('json/MasterObject.json');

                httpPromise.then(function(response) {
                    deferred.resolve(response);
                }, function(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });

                return deferred.promise;
            }
        };
    })
```

ngRoute config with resolve that checks if Model.formStuff is available and if not attempts to get it before loading the route which needs the data.

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/someRoute', {
        controller: 'someController',
        templateUrl: 'views/someView.html',
        resolve: {
          getFormTemplate: function (Model, jsonFactory) {
            if (!Model.formStuff) {
                Model.formStuff = jsonFactory.getFormStuff();
                return Model.formStuff;
            } else {
                return Model.formStuff;
            }
        } 
    }
 })
```

EDIT: Adding the Model factory and controller where Model.formStuff is referenced. The Model.formStuff is dynamically added in a different controller and is not a pre-defined property...I inherited this code so not sure why it is handled like that.

```
angular.module('example', [])
    .factory('Model', ['$resource',
        function($resource) {
            return {
                query: function() {
                    return data;
                },
                get: function(id) {
                    return findById(id);
                },
                set: function(item) {
                    addItem(item);
                },
                put: function(item) {
                    updateItem(item);
                },
                del: function(id) {
                    removeItem(id);
                },
                getLoginUser: function(id) {
                    removeItem(id);
                },
                islogin: false
            };
        }
    ])
```

basic controller example showing how Model.formStuff is normally used.

```
angular.module(...)
  .controller("someController", function(Model) {        
    $scope.someField = Model.formStuff[0].someProp;
    var someVar = Model.formStuff.[0].otherProp;

    // bunch of other code...
  });
```

Comment: You need to `reject` the promise and not `resolve` it in case of an error/unauthorized request

Comment: So does that mean just using 'reject:{}' rather than 'resolve:{}' in the route is all that needs to be done?

Comment: No, `deferred.reject` rather than `deferred.resolve` (based on the results returned from the server, or `deferred.reject` whenever you get response error

Comment: I see, so doing that will allow the loading of the route to wait until that data is available?

Comment: No, if you reject the promise the change of state is aborted and a [$routeChangeError](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#example) is triggered - then you can redirect the user to another state

Comment: In my case all I need to do is delay the loading of the route until the actual data is available.

Comment: Oh, now I see that. sorry. Since you save the promise inside `Model` than on the second time you always returning a resolved promise, that's why you don't get the delay. You need to include the implementation of `Model` for more specific instructions

Comment: @AlonEitan edit made to original post.

Comment: I didn't see your update before posting my answer. When working with $resource objects, you have to be careful concerning resolving as the $resource immediately returns an empty object and later modifies it. See a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35969061/angular-ui-router-resolve-not-waiting-for-promise-to-resolve-due-state-switchi/35970556#35970556 But I don't think this is the problem in your case. Could you please provide your controller implementation?

Answer (score 1):

The code doesn't look that wrong. Please be sure to also handle the error case, otherwise the promise you return will never be rejected and the router will wait forever in case of some error. So you should call `deferred.reject(error)` in your error callback.

If you don't need any special processing on the data, you could directly return the promise of the `$http.get()` call like so:

```
getFormStuff = function() { 
  return $http.get('json/MasterObject.json');
}
```

What could possibly be the problem in your case is the controller definition. Do you inject a value named like the key in your resolve object into the controller? Otherwise the data will not be passed there...

```
angular.module(...)
  .controller("someController", function(getFormTemplate) {
    // do anything with the resolved data...
  });
```

Another suggestion: Instead of handling the caching stuff directly in the resolve block, why not creating a special service that caches the data and just resolving like so:

```
resolve: {
  getFormTemplate: function (MyCachingModel) {
    return MyCachingModel.promiseToTemplate()
  }
}
```

... and then moving the current logic into this caching service. This makes reasoning much clearer as your logic is not spread into the router config.

Comment: I've updated post with controller example. I do also intend to abstract things out more like you mentioned.

Comment: In your updated code the controller doesn't get injected the `resolve`d property (called `getFormTemplate` in your case). This could be the reason why the controller is called before anything is resolved at all.

Comment: I see, so that property needs to be injected into the controller in order for it resolve properly? Or am I misunderstanding?